# Diferença entre usar generics e "any" no TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, tipagem, genéricos

Quando eu sei que é preferível usar *generics* ou `any` no TypeScript?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

O ideal é não usar `any`. Dá para viver sem ele, só que alguns casos pode dar mais trabalho, por isso há raros casos que pode ser interessante usar. `any` é voltar ser JavaScript e todo (ou quase todo) problema que isso causa.

Toda vez que usa esse tipo está admitindo que não sabe o tipo e o mais adequado é usando-o ou tem alguma ligação com algo do JavaScript que não tem tem tipo (lembrando que é possível [ter os tipos do que vem do JS se eles forem declarados separadamente](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/456677/101)).

Para uso em TS "puro", você usa quando quer uma facilidade que aquela rotina realmente aceita qualquer coisa e faz o mesmo algoritmo nela. Se começar ter muito `if` para verificar o tipo e decidir o que fazer já está errado. Em alguns casos pode ser útil, mas é bem raro e eu deixaria para alguém muito experiente fazê-lo, na dúvida não use `any`.

Eu vejo muito programador usar `any` por preguiça ou por estar mais acostumado com JS. Esses são péssimos motivos para seu uso e o código já está condenado, até porque não será o único erro que essa pessoa cometerá.

Mesmo quando um objeto pode ter mais de um tipo, ele não precisa ter todos, então um *union type* pode ser usado. A ideia é ser o mais específico no tipo tanto quanto possível, se não der um tipo, tente 2 ou 3. Todos tipos (*any*) é só quando realmente aceita todos tipos, que não faz diferença o que vem, e isso é muito raro.

Antes mesmo de um *union type* deve preferir outra solução de polimorfismo, por exemplo *generics*, então assim está especificando um tipo a ser usado na chamado do método ou tipo maior. Você consegue fazer um método ou estrutura de dados genérico/generalizado, como o próprio diz, mas ele será tratado de forma específica quando chamar e isso será mais seguro (quem sabe um dia até seria mais rápido, hoje isso não é melhorado por depender do JS).

*Generics* é um mecanismo usado quando algo precisa processar mais de um tipo, mas quer que em cada chamada àquilo o tipo seja diferente, mas faz sempre a mesma coisa. Ele se assemelha ao *union type* porque costuma ter alguma restrição, você não pode usar qualquer tipo de fato, mas alguns que fazem sentido, então há uma [*constraint*](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html#generic-constraints) dizendo qual é o tipo pai que é aceito ali. Ao contrário do *union type* que permite unir tipos diversos, o genérico só aceita um tipo que estabelece herança.

Eu mostro um [exemplo onde um tipo único não é ideal](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/451967/101).

Na prática a execução de ambos será igual, mas na compilação o *any* aceita tudo, o *generics* pode ter uma restrição. Se você não usar uma restrição, o que quase sempre é um erro, então acaba sendo a mesma coisa em TypeScript, porque depois de gerado o JS tudo vira *any* até porque é só isso que tem em JS (em outras linguagens existem outras vantagens). Mesmo efeito:

```
function funcao<T>(p: T): T {
    return p;
}

function funcao(p: any): any {
    return p;
}
```

Já isto muda um pouco:

```
function funcao<T>(p1: T, p2: T): T {
    return p1;
}

function funcao(p1: any, p2 : any): any {
    return p1;
}
```

Porque assim o primeiro exige que os dois parâmetros sejam do mesmo tipo, já o segundo código não exige isso, já é uma diferença semântica importante.

E isto muda muito:

```
function funcao<T extends number>(p1: T): T {
    return p1 + p2;
}

function funcao(p1: any): any {
    return p1 + p2;
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/TypeScript/GenericsAny.ts).

Com a restrição você está estabelecendo um limite do que pode usar, o primeiro pode dar erro se não for possível somar os objetos.

Comment: Muito bom, obrigada!