# Qual é a utilidade do 'declare' do Typescript?

Tags: typescript, declaração-de-variável

Estou lendo a [documentação do Typescript](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/typescript-in-5-minutes.html#generics) e encontrei o `declare`:

> You can declare your own types that use generics:
>
> interface Backpack {   add: (obj: Type) => void;   get: () =>
> Type; }   // This line is a shortcut to tell TypeScript there is a //
> constant called `backpack`, and to not worry about where it came from.
> declare const backpack: Backpack;   // object is a string,
> because we declared it above as the variable part of Backpack. const
> object = backpack.get();   // Since the backpack variable is a string,
> you can't pass a number to the add function. backpack.add(23);
> Argument of type 'number' is not assignable to parameter of type
> 'string'.

Pela documentação do TS, entendi como 'fazer funcionar' o `declare`, mas ainda não entendi como é aplicada essa 'funcionalidade' e porque foi criada.

qual é a utilidade de somente declarar uma variável/constante usando o `declare` e porque não realmente definir a variável/constante?

Comment: `declare` é usado para definir uma tipagem de algo, por exemplo, os tipos de alguma variável aplicada ao env global (`globalThis`). Um outro exemplo foi um caso em que usei o esse recurso para estender globalmente um tipo que era definido pelo framework Express, sem alterar a tipagem oficial do framework. Eu uso o declare em arquivos `.d.ts`, onde ficam essas definicoes de tipos para facilitar o trabalho do compilador. Essas definicoes não são transpiladas para codigo JS, apenas servem para auxiliar o TS quando o mesmo nao reconhece os tipos de algum dado que vc esteja trabalhando.

Comment: @CmteCardeal Sim, a forma que tenho mais visto o `declare` é em arquivos `.d.ts` como `declare module`, mas o que acontece se existirem duas funções com o mesmo nome por exemplo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Um dos principais objetivos do design do TypeScript é a possibilidade de adoção gradual. Isto é, se alguém quiser introduzir TypeScript em um projeto já consolidado em JavaScript, deve conseguir fazer isso de forma não tão dolorosa.

O `declare` é uma ferramenta que ajuda nesse sentido. É uma palavra-chave que permite que se ateste ao compilador que uma variável, com um certo *nome* e de um determinado *tipo*, existe naquele contexto. O compilador simplesmente irá confiar na declaração e assumir que ela está correta conforme a especificação dada.

#### Type safety

Sob o ponto de vista da segurança de tipos, o `declare` é "inseguro" de forma similar ao `as` (*type assertions*), pois os dois funcionam de modo a permitir que o desenvolvedor *ateste* algo que o compilador não consegue provar, seja por falta de informações ou por limitações tecnológicas no próprio [type system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_system).

É sempre importante tomar cuidado com esse tipo de feature pois, embora extremamente convenientes, elas introduzem "buracos" no sistema de tipos, que podem comprometer a segurança de tipos de todo o programa. Isso porque, ao utilizar `declare` ou `as`, o comipilador simplesmente aceita e segue a especificação fornecida pelo código—a partir desse ponto, a segurança de tipos naquele região fica como *responsabilidade* dos próprios desenvolvedores, que devem ter **certeza** de que a asserção está *correta*.

#### Alguns exemplos

Tradicionalmente, antes da popularização de *bundlers* e de sistemas de módulos em JavaScript, era muito comum incluir bibliotecas JavaScript simplesmente adicionando um `<script>` ao final do markup da página, que introduzia o *entrypoint* da biblioteca no objeto global, `window`.

Sob o ponto de vista do TypeScript, o problema com isso é que o compilador não tem como saber o que foi introduzido pelo script. Nesse caso, uma possível solução é utilizar o `declare` para especificar ao compilador quais símbolos a biblioteca exporta a  partir do objeto global.

Por exemplo, `@types/jquery` faz justamente isso. [Veja aqui no GitHub.](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/jquery/misc.d.ts#L6622-L6623)

Um outro caso comum é declarar constantes definidas pelo processo de *bundling* do código. Por exemplo, o `esbuild` permite que se defina constantes durante o processo ([ver aqui](https://esbuild.github.io/api/#define)). Como o TypeScript não está diretamente integrado a essa ferramenta, é necessário utilizar o declare para que se possa utilizar a definição no código fonte.

Por exemplo, assumindo que se passe `--define:DEBUG=true`, pode-se utilizar o seguinte código para que se declare a definição ao TS:

```
declare const DEBUG: true;

// Em seguida, pode-se utilizar normalmente.
console.log(DEBUG);
```

#### Diferenças em relação à declarações "normais"

Declarações de variáveis "comuns", usando `let`, `const` ou `var`, são diferentes do `declare` pois elas *exigem* um valor a ser atribuído à variável, nem que seja o `undefined` implicitamente. A função do `declare` é diferente: não de *atribuir* um valor a um nome, mas simplesmente dizer que, naquele nome, *existe* um valor de determinado tipo.

Comment: Quem deu o negativo poderia pelo menos justificar, né? Se quiser adicionar uma outra resposta, melhor ainda. ^-^

Comment: Não fui eu quem deu o negativo, mas o debate sobre uso da palavra chave `declare` é bem mais amplo. Eu to tomando coragem para escrever uma resposta a essa pergunta pois é muito texto e cada caso de uso reflete de forma diferente no js gerado.

Comment: @AugustoVasques, o debate de fato é amplo, mas IMO elencar todos os detalhes não deveria ser o objetivo de respostas como essas—do contrário, há até o risco de fugir do escopo da pergunta. Sobre o impacto no código gerado, poderia fornecer um exemplo?

Comment: É importante esclarecer os casos de uso do `declare` pois é utilizado na criação dos [arquivos de declaração](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/456686/137387) pois o uso da palavra chave não se aplica apenas a exposição de variáveis, o uso de `declare` se estende a todos os tipos criáveis com o Typescript(namespaces, classes, interfaces, metodos,..). O impacto no código se dá ao se criar manualmente esses arquivos onde é possivel impor uma camada de restrição aos tipos expostos ao consumidor do arquivo de declarações.

Comment: https://itnext.io/mastering-declaration-files-the-key-to-typescripts-type-magic-fe4483a86645

Answer (score -1):

A palavra-chave `declare` serve para declarar a existência de uma variável (com o tipo definido) externa ao TypeScript

Você vai encontrar muito nos arquivos `.d.ts` gerados pelo compilador ao criar uma biblioteca com o TypeScript. No caso de uma aplicação, você não vai precisar gerar os tipos, apenas compilar para JavaScript, mas, se quiser criar uma biblioteca que vai ser utilizada por outras aplicações, você vai querer que o compilador gere os tipos. Lembrando que, mesmo uma biblioteca feita em TypeScript, apenas os arquivos `.d.ts` e `.js` (gerados pelo compilador) são distribuidos ([exemplo](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@angular/core?activeTab=code))

Algumas bibliotecas são feitas com JavaScript puro e sua tipagem é criada manual e separadamente, quando você for as instalar via NPM, também precisará instalar o pacote de seu tipo, por exemplo, [`fabric`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fabric) e [`@types/fabric`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/fabric) (o Fabric.js foi convertido para TypeScript a partir da versão 6), nesses casos, usará o `declare` nos arquivos `.d.ts` que criar

Outro caso muito comum é quando você precisa carregar uma biblioteca JavaScript externa (normalmente porque não é disponibilizada no NPM), como o [Google Maps](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/load-maps-js-api#typescript) (há biliotecas no NPM como o [`@googlemaps/js-api-loader`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@googlemaps/js-api-loader), mas elas apenas oferecem um meio para carregar o Google Maps), nesse caso, você precisa "avisar" ao TypeScript que a variável é criada externamente, exemplo:

```
declare const google: /* ... */;

const map = new google.maps.Map(/* ... */);
```